# \csname not working as expected

Tags: tex-core

The following code prints ==atname==

```
\def\atname{atname}
\def\xxx{name}
\def\at{at}
==\csname\at\xxx\endcsname==
\bye
```

but this does not:

```
\def\@name{atname}
\def\xxx{name}
\def\at{@}
==\csname\at\xxx\endcsname==
\bye
```

Why, and how can I make this work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`\def\@name{atname}` has not defined `\@name`, but `\@` with parameter text `name`. Also in plain TeX, the default catcode for `@` is 12.

```
\catcode`\@=11
\def\@name{atname}
\def\xxx{name}
\def\at{@}
==\csname\at\xxx\endcsname==
\bye
```

Comment: Ah, that was stupid - I use plain Tex only in Latex class and style files, where I had a problem and tried to simplify my question; hadn't realized that latex changes @'s catcode. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

A control sequence definition is composed of three parts:

1. the control sequence name;
2. the parameter text;
3. the replacement text.

The *parameter text* is whatever is placed between the control sequence name and the open brace `{`<sub>1</sub> that delimits the replacement text. It *can* contain parameter tokens `#1`…`#9`, but also other tokens.

A control sequence can be formed by a sequence of one or more letters (a letter, in this context, is a character with category code 11) or by a *single* non letter (any category code).

However, control sequence names can be formed with the expansion of `\csname`: all character tokens resulting from the full expansion of the tokens up to the matching `\endcsname` will be used, independently of their category code.

Under the normal setting, `@` has category code 12, so doing

```
\def\@name{atname}
```

defines `\@`, because a single non letter ends the scanning for the control sequence name. The parameter text is the token list `name`, which is *required* to follow `\@` at usage time.

So you go through by doing

```
\catcode`@=11 % make @ a letter
\def\@name{atname}
\catcode`@=12 % go back to the default
\def\xxx{name}
\def\at{@}
==\csname\at\xxx\endcsname==
\bye
```

or

```
\expandafter\def\csname @name\endcsname{atname}
\def\xxx{name}
\def\at{@}
==\csname\at\xxx\endcsname==
\bye
```

because `\expandafter` forms the control sequence name from the expansion of `\csname` *before* `\def` does its job.